# Is it possible to review questions/answers by any specific Tags?

Tags: discussion, review

I have one question.

Is it possible to review `questions/answers` by any specific Tag? like i said i want to review only android tag `questions/answers`.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. Click review/{queue-name} and set filter you like:

> [image]

Comment: Thnx. it worked...